# Is `command -v program` always executable?

Tags: linux, command, posix, executable

I am using the `command -v "program" >/dev/null 2>&1` construct if I need to POSIX-ly find out if such `program` is installed in an `if`-statement.

---

From its help page is not clear, whether it checks only for path or also for the executable bit?

```
$ command --help
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
...
      -v    print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Careful though that `command -v` will still consider builtins, which take precedence over executables. Try e.g. `command -V test` or `command -V printf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command -v` uses the PATH to find the executable.

It also checks the permission. If you try `command -v a_non_executable_file`, nothing will be printed.

You can try `strace bash -c 'command -v grep'` you will see that the `access(2)` system call is executed (this system call check the user's permissions for a file). `command -v` will search in the PATH the first file you can execute.